# Thymeleaf not able to post collections / lists of objects

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm creating a web-application with spring MVC, hibernate and thymeleaf.
I have a page where I can manage users, on this page you should be able to place and remove users from groups.
I am doing this with 2 multiple select boxes.
I added a jquery script what handles the movement of users from the one select box to the other one.
But when i submit, my Group.users object list is empty and I do not get any exceptions. 
Does anyone has some advice?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I just discovered that all thymeleaf attributes inside the html tag "option", aren't compiled. Except for the th:each attr.
So it's pretty clear the problem is in my thymeleaf file.

Thymeleaf / edit.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <div th:replace="template :: css"></div>
    <title>Edit group</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".clickable").click(function() {
                    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                        $(this).removeClass("selected").addClass("unselected");
                        $('#userGroupContainer').append(this);
                        $("option:selected").css("background-color", "red");
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass("unselected").addClass("selected");
                        $('#userGroupContainerSelected').append(this);
                        $("option:selected").css("background-color", "green");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="bodyWrap">
            <div th:replace="template :: logo">Logo</div>
            <div th:replace="template :: nav">Nav</div>
            <div th:replace="template :: messages">Header</div>
            <div id="backGround">
                <div id="contentWrap">
                    <form action="@{edit}"
                        th:action="@{${#httpServletRequest.servletPath}}"
                        th:object="${group}" th:method="post">
                        <h1 th:unless="${group.id}">Add group</h1>
                        <h1 th:if="${group.id}">Edit group</h1>
                        <hr />
                        <div th:replace="template :: messages">Header</div>
                        <div class="newFile">
                            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
                            <table class="newFile">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name:</th>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="50" th:field="${group.name}" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Description:</th>
                                    <td><textarea th:field="${group.description}"></textarea></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br /> users <br />
                            <select multiple="multiple" id="userGroupContainer">
                                <option th:each="u : ${userNotInGroup}" th:text="${u.displayName}" class="clickable unselected" th:value="${u}" ></option>
                            </select>

<!-- It's all about the select box under this comment -->

                            <select multiple="multiple" id="userGroupContainerSelected" th:field="*{users}">
                                <option th:each="ug, rowStat : ${group.users}" th:text="${ug.displayName}" th:value="${ug}" class="clickable selected">Selected</option>
                            </select>

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <button th:unless="${group.id}" type="submit">Add</button>
                                <button th:if="${group.id}" type="submit">Update</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

example of the 2 multiple select boxes:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".clickable").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
     $(this).removeClass("selected").addClass("unselected");
     $('#userGroupContainer').append(this);
     $("option:selected").css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
     $(this).removeClass("unselected").addClass("selected");
     $('#userGroupContainerSelected').append(this);
     $("option:selected").css("background-color", "green");
    }
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="userGroupContainer">
       <option class="clickable unselected" >Example</option>
      </select>
      <select multiple="multiple" id="userGroupContainerSelected" th:field="*{users}">
       <option class="clickable selected">Selected</option>
      </select>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/management/edit/{groupId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editGroup(ModelMap model, Principal principal, @PathVariable("groupId") Long groupId) {
    Group group = groupService.findGroupById(groupId);
    User user = new User();
    List<User> userNotInGroup = userService.findUsersNotInGroup(group);
    model.addAttribute("userNotInGroup", userNotInGroup);
    model.addAttribute("group", group);
    return "management/groups/edit";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/management/edit/{groupId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editGroup(@Valid Group group, BindingResult result, Model model, @PathVariable("groupId") Long groupId) {
    model.addAttribute("group", group);
    System.out.println("USERS: " + group.getUsers());
    groupService.saveGroup(group);
    return "redirect:/management/list";
}
```

Group Entity / object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS")
public class Group extends DomainObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "GROUPS_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "GROUPS_SEQ", sequenceName = "GROUPS_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @JoinTable(name = "USERS_GROUPS")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<User> users;

    @JoinTable(name = "GROUPS_ROLES")
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Role> roles;


    public Collection<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Collection<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

User Entity / Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User extends DomainObject implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = ;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @NotNull
    private Long ID;
    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME")
    @NotNull
    private String displayName;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    @NotNull
    private String emailAddress;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "LAST_LOGIN")
    private Date lastLogin;
    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_DATE")
    private Date modifiedDate;
    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY")
    private String modifiedBy;
    @Transient
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean admin;
    @Nullable
    @JoinTable(name = "USERS_GROUPS")
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Group> groups;

    public Date getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }

    public void setLastLogin(Date lastLogin) {
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public Collection<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(Collection<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.ID = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against using database Entity objects as Spring model objects, this leaves your app to potential abuse. Instead you should create specific Spring model objects and transfer the data you want over to the database Entities. I also suspect that this is why this is not working for you, Spring is trying to coerce the parameters `users` to the `User` class.

Comment: I appreciate your comment but my boss wants it this way.
I also think not that is my problem.
I think it's something with thyme leaf, because my list of objects is always empty.
Not only with the method I use now but also when I post the list to a temp list.
Do you have any other suggestions?
@GeorgeLee